# Verifying that the account belongs to the person that claims

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

**Context**

Sign-up form and one of the fields is Instagram account
When the user will finish sing up, there's a link to the person's Insta account
(No integrations)

**Goal**

I want to make sure the user can only sign up with his own Instagram,
much like e-mail verification

**My thoughts**

I took a look at the Instagram API documentation and didn't find an option for it. Any thoughts about how to do that?

There would be an option to use the Insta auth basic, allow the user to sign-up via Instagram. Although this seems to be a proper overkill and it's getting deprecated anyways.

Comment: Have you checked Instagram OAuth 2.0 documentation? https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: Yes, I have. As I understood that will get deprecated on the beginning of 2020. Is there any way to send a direct message with a code to the user maybe?

Comment: You are right, that API is being slowly deprecated. The new one is called Graph API which you can check here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/ 

This will not be deprecated anytime soon.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Checked both these docs previously, didn't find an answer for my question. That's why I turned here.